# alternatives of controller method

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am using this code in my laravel 5.3 project but it says that it is badcallmethodexception , I found that controller method is no longer available in new version , how to write this code?
this is my code:

```
Route::controller('notifications', 'NotificationController');
```

inside this controller there is this code:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    return view('notification');
}

public function postNotify(Request $request)
{
    $notifyText = e($request->input('notify_text'));


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using default laravel controller methods you need to define which method should be called for route.

```
Route::get('notifications', 'NotificationController@getIndex');
Route::post('notifications', 'NotificationController@postNotify');
```

Answer (score 0):

Write route as :

```
Route::post('notification','NotificationController@method-name');
```

Here **post** is method type that you can use as per your requirement. or else you can use resource as

```
Route::resource('notification','NotificationController');
```

**Resource** can be used only for index,create,store,update and destroy method.

Laravel document : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers